# How detect HTML attributes in PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am currently developing a glossary to my website. This glossary is included in a product description.

Currently I am doing a loop on a table contained all the glossary terms, and in this loop I use preg_replace ()

I try to optimize and fix bugs in my regular expression, but I can not, I'm stuck on this problem for two days now without any solution.

My main problem is I do not want to replace the term found in the lexicon HTML attributes `title = "*"` `src = "*"` and `alt = "*"` ...

Here is where I am currently blocked: https://regex101.com/r/oJ0qC4/1

Can u tell me how can I do this? Do you have a solution for me? And what's wrong with my regex?

Thanks.

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: In many cases I think it's valid to use regex for HTML operations, despite the general hate. In this case though, you are waaaaay better off with a parser. You can get all the values you seek very easily with a parser, whereas you will have many edge cases if you use regex.

Comment: You can use [(*SKIP)(*F)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) to skip something. See [your updated sample](https://regex101.com/r/oJ0qC4/2).